# Работа с DBXJSON

Tags: delphi, json

В ходе освоения DBXJSON в DelphiXE столкнулся с парой проблемм

Пример ответа JSON, который будем парсить:

```
{"num1":631,
 "num2":31,
 "num3":64,
 "data":"{
   \"dat1\":[0,1,2,3,4],
   \"dat2\":null,
   \"dat3\":true,
   \"dat4\":[1,1,1,1,1],
   \"dat5\":{
     \"dat4str1\":11,
     \"dat4str2\":0,
     \"dat4str3\":0,
     \"dat4str4\":2
   },
   \"sdata\":{
     \"sdata1\":12,
     \"sdata2\":48,
     \"sdata3\":395,
   },
   \"dat5\":[[0,1,1],[0,1,1],[0,1,1]]
 }"
}
```

**1**. Если ответ в JSONText, то получаем объект целиком:

```
JSONObj:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONText) As TJSONObject;
```

Потом выделяем data в отдельный:

```
JSONData:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONObj.Get('data').JsonValue.Value) As TJSONObject;
```

А потом надо так же выделить dat5, но строка:

```
JSONData4:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONData.Get('dat5').JsonValue.Value) As TJSONObject;
```

уже не сработает, из-за слешей в названии \"dat5\"

Как быть? Из php кстити всё парсится на ура.

**2**. Как считывать значиния null и true?

Comment: Решил проблемму следующим образом:
JSONData:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONObj.Get('data').JsonValue.Value).ToString) As TJSONObject;
так мы представляем то, что в data как объект, а потом с ним работаем уже обычно
JSONData5:=TJSONObject.ParseJSONValue(JSONData.Get('dat5').JsonValue.ToString) As TJSONObject;
dat4str2:=StrToInt(JSONData5.Get('dat4str2').JsonValue.ToString);

А для boolean значений 
Dat3:=StrToBool(JSONData.Get('dat3').JsonValue.ToString);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще странно что " оформлено как \". И " и ', нормально воспринимаются JavaScript'ом. А в JSON этих \ вообще быть не должно.

1. Заменяете \" на ".
2. Не знаю на счет DBXJSON, не пользуюсь им, но исп. superobject было бы так:
   <code>
   var  Json:ISuperObject; 
   begin
   json := SO('JSON Text');
   if json.N['data.dat2'].IsType(stNull) then
   //Data.Dat2 = NULL

if json.B['data.dat3'] then 
//Data.Dat3 = TRUE 
end;
</code>